# Firebase onNewToken crashes on Android > 8.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, android-8.0-oreo

I have this following code, it crashes on Android 8.0 and up but works fine on older Android Versions:

```
package com.myapp.firebase;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.myapp.utils.SendPushTokenToServer;

public class CloudMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(final String refreshToken) {
        super.onNewToken(refreshToken);

        handler = new Handler();

        if (refreshToken != null) {
            if (!refreshToken.equals("") && !refreshToken.equals("null")) {
//                        new SendPushTokenToServer(getApplicationContext(), refreshToken).execute();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new SendPushTokenToServer(getApplicationContext(), refreshToken).execute();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d("MyApp", "Message From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

//            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
//                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
//                scheduleJob();
//            } else {
//                // Handle message within 10 seconds
//                handleNow();
//            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        handler.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

I have tried to run my token upload AsyncTask on the main thread but also just like that.

As for errors I get a RunTimeException when I try to start the AsyncTask but I don't get any closer details on what's wrong.

EDIT: Here is the (Not so helpful) logfile:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at android.os.Handler.
>   (Handler.java:203)   at android.os.Handler. (Handler.java:117)
>   at com.myapp.firebase.CloudMessaging.onNewToken
>   (CloudMessaging.java:26)   at
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd (Unknown
>   Source:423)   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run (Unknown Source:26)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)   at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run (Unknown
>   Source:7)   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)

Comment: can you post your crash logs?

Comment: Yes as I said it's not much but I put it into the post...